# Button not working to trigger slide in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written code to pull up a selection panel using css, HTML, and Jquery UI I have added a test button to trigger a slide to the next screen, However the button is not working and the slide is not happening. Upon review of my code everything should work unless I missed something. Any way to get this to work?

HTML

```
<div id="toggle">
        <div id="background>

            <div id="Layer0"><img src="images/Layer0.png"></div>
            <div id="Layer1"><img src="images/Layer1.png"></div>
            <div id="VneckTshirtRectangle"><img src="images/VneckTshirtRectangle.png"></div>
            <div id="VneckTshirtImage"><button type="button" id="button"><img src="images/VneckTshirtImage.png"></button></div>
            <div id="VneckTShirt"><img src="images/VneckTShirt.png"></div>
            <div id="VneckTShirtBorder"><img src="images/VneckTShirtBorder.png"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
    $( '#button' ).click(function() {
    $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
    });
</script>
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

 #background 
{ 
     left: 0px; 
     top: 0px; 
     position: relative; 
     margin-left: auto; 
     margin-right: auto; 
     width: 1300px;
     height: 1400px; 
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index:0;
    } 

 #Layer0 
{ 
     left: 0px; 
     top: 0px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 1300px;
     height: 1400px;
     z-index:1;
} 

 #Layer1 
{ 
     left: 0px; 
     top: 294px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 1300px;
     height: 812px;
     z-index:2;
} 

 #VneckTshirtRectangle 
{ 
     left: 71px; 
     top: 418px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 252px;
     height: 252px;
     z-index:3;
} 

 #VneckTshirtImage 
{ 
     left: 138px; 
     top: 457px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 118px;
     height: 174px;
     z-index:4;
} 

 #VneckTShirt 
{ 
     left: 120px; 
     top: 631px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 154px;
     height: 19px;
     z-index:5;
} 

 #VneckTShirtBorder 
{ 
     left: 72px; 
     top: 419px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 250px;
     height: 250px;
     z-index:6;
}
```

## FIDDLE

Comment: It looks like the HTML you've provided is malformed.  One quick one I can see immediately is the one below:

 `<div id="background>`

Take care to make sure that you're property closing your quotes (") when you're putting your HTML together.  It's a good habit to also make sure you're closing your elements.  From the code you provided, it doesn't seem like you've closed the 'background' div either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the z-index of  is low than other so your div is overlapped by other div which does not allow the button to be clicked.

all you need to do is increase the z-index of `<div id="VneckTshirtImage">` more than other div. Then your button will be clickable.....

this is the tested code of your fiddle, just increase the z-index:

```
#VneckTshirtImage {
    left: 138px;
    top: 457px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 118px;
    height: 174px;
    z-index:8;
}
```

Check the code and let me know...

Happy Coding.